# Cannot access CiviCRM: "Undefined property: CRM_Core_Config"

Tags: wordpress, php, access, undefined

With CiviCRM 5.69.2 on WordPress 6.4.2 and PHP 8.1, I'm getting the following when trying to access CiviCRM:

> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your
> site admin email inbox for instructions.

Following are the logs:

```
PHP Warning: Undefined property: CRM_Core_Config::$extensionsDir in /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/System.php on line 89, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=civi_options

PHP Warning: Undefined property: CRM_Core_Config::$extensionsURL in /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/System.php on line 90, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=civi_options

PHP Warning: Undefined property: CRM_Core_Config::$uploadDir in /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/System.php on line 92, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=civi_options

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Invalid currency ""\n\n thrown in /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Money.php on line 85, referer: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=civi_options
```

This is a very small and simple CiviCRM install that was working a few months ago.

Any insight as to next steps?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Issue was related to `WP_CONTENT_DIR` being defined in `wp-config.php`.

Full details in [this thread](https://forum.cloudron.io/topic/10924/v3-5-gives-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website-please-check-your-site-admin-email-inbox-for-instructions/).